# Javascript API to generate calendar events

Tags: calendar, jsom, sharepoint-calendar

When a user clicked on "Save" button in the New form of calendar list, I want to save the dates that the user scheduled the event in another list.

Based on the inputs provided in the form, I am doing this. The problem is with Recurrent events.

When a recurrent event is going to be saved, I want all dates of that recurrent event.

I read the inputs using javascript/jquery, I want some javascript API that will generate the required dates.

**Example:** If I want the dates of first Friday for next ten months, it should provide.

Please tell me if any javascript API is there like that.